# What can be the regular expression for the following variable in openscript?

Tags: regex, oracle, performance, openscript

What can be the regular expression for the following variable in openscript?
*Siebel_CORRLIB_ROWID_1628008925187__RowID_N0_1*#_2115B330442 - this is the string to be resolved using http.solve method.

this is the response from which regular expression is to be created:
SWECmd=GotoView&SWEView=EPIC+Relationship+Orders&SWERF=1&SWEHo=10.59.16.175&SWEBU=1&SWEApplet0=EPIC+Relationship+Form+Applet&SWERowId0=2-115B-330442&SWEApplet1=EPIC+Contact+Refill+Order+List+Applet&SWERowId1=1-15XR5L34`0`2`anot`0`1`0`apm`0`vrn`S_A1`1`0`apm`0`vrn`S_A2`0`6`Command